# Mahjong Betting Rules

Tags: mahjong, betting

Have been playing Mahjong for over 45 years and played today with a lady who filled in and we had a discussion regarding payout for betting.
For purposes of this question:
Playing with 4 players at the table and the 5th as the better.
Player A calls Mahjong with a self drawn tile.

The hand was a 25 cent hand which would then be doubled to 50 cents since it was a self drawn tile for Mahjong.
Since it was also bet on the bettor would also get 50 cents for the winning hand.
SO each player would pay both the winning player and the bettor each 50 cents. Total for each of the two players would be $1.50 each. Am I correct???

The lady who filled in was insistent about the following.
She said since the player who called Mahjong was also bet on by her then the total that each player needed to pay both the winning player and she, the bettor, was to be double the 50 cents to equal $1.00 total to each of the two players.
This would then make the player with the winning hand paid a total of $3.00 and the bettor also be paid $3.00.
So instead of each of the other 3 players paying out $1.50 to each for a total of $3.00, she insisted it was to be doubled since it was also bet on to a $1.00 payout for each the winning player and also the bettor for a total payout for the 2 players to $6.00.
She insisted that this was National Mahjong Rules.
As I stated have been playing a very long time and have never had any player state this.
Thanks much for your responses.

Comment: I have never heard about betting rules for Mahjong. In principle, I understand the notion of making a bet on the outcome of a game, but a situation where the players receive or pay to an outside better seems like a conflict of interest.

Answer (score 4):

The official mahjong rules do not allow for "cross" bets by players on each other, or by outside parties on or against players.

Now this lady may have been playing by "house" rules in "her" games. But those rules do not apply to your table unless you all agree to them.

Answer (score -2):

I used to play this type of man Jongg.  In TX, the only time the bet was doubled was if the winner was East wind.  Could have been a table rule.